# How to include a vlc installation in my setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vlc, setup-project

I'm doing my installer solution and kept on the steps of the tutorials and everything worked best. I had the need to include vlc one of my usercontrol to display videos and not as vlc include in my setup project

Comment: What are you using to build your installer?

Answer (score 0):

Install it silently with Process.Start when the program loads, make sure to check it does not exist first:

[How to install VLC silently](http://adriank.org/deployment-vlc-media-player-2-0-4/)

[Process.Start in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx)

and, of course, include the vlc installer in to your application so that it deploys with the solution ready for install.

You should also make your end user aware it is being installed, pay attention to licensing etc.

Another option, probably simpler but not what you asked - include the COM component: [How to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAdKP79jT6o)